# Unknown error after pushing web app through heroku master

Tags: python, git, heroku, pip, requirements.txt

I was pushing my app through heroku master but this was the error I received. I tried pip install absl-py, but the requirements are already satisfied.

Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in /Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.11.0)

This is my first time deploying a web app. Pls help

terminal:

```
Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Processing /tmp/build/80754af9/absl-py_1607439979954/work
remote:        ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/absl-py_1607439979954/work'
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to skin-lesion-detector.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/skin-lesion-detector.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/skin-lesion-detector.git'
```

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
absl-py @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/absl-py_1607439979954/work
alabaster==0.7.12
anaconda-client==1.7.2
anaconda-navigator==1.10.0
anaconda-project @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/anaconda-project_1610472525955/work
applaunchservices==0.2.1
appnope @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/4f734db2-9ca8-4d8b-5b29-6ca15b4b4772/volume/appnope_1606859466979/work
appscript @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/aa928f42-721f-468a-5637-76f7349085f8/volume/appscript_1594840167539/work
argh==0.26.2
argon2-cffi @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c4db8eed-7de0-4d68-400c-2ea7e21d3750/volume/argon2-cffi_1596828478065/work
asgiref==3.3.1
asn1crypto @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/asn1crypto_1596577642040/work
astor==0.8.1
astroid @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/b22b518b-f584-4586-5ee9-55bfa4fca96e/volume/astroid_1592495912194/work
astropy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/4d41c9c8-7ad9-470a-4924-a86cb5c771d4/volume/astropy_1606922930702/work
astunparse==1.6.3
async-generator==1.10
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/attrs_1604765588209/work
autopep8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/autopep8_1596578164842/work
Babel @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/babel_1607110387436/work
backcall==0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/backports.functools_lru_cache_1605305165209/work
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size_1608222128777/work
backports.tempfile==1.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/beautifulsoup4_1601924105527/work
bitarray @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/6128f15f-808f-4816-5943-7b9060c9e4fe/volume/bitarray_1605065121867/work
bkcharts==0.2
bleach @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/bleach_1600439572647/work
bokeh @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/17495d14-5b57-4c12-6d6b-201edb177b9e/volume/bokeh_1603297848703/work
boto==2.49.0
Bottleneck==1.3.2
brotlipy==0.7.0
cachetools==4.1.1
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/2aa8abfe-8b8d-4889-78d9-837b74c3cd64/volume/cffi_1606255119410/work
chardet @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9efbf151-b45b-463d-6340-a5c399bf00b7/volume/chardet_1607706825988/work
click==7.1.2
cloudpickle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cloudpickle_1598884132938/work
clyent==1.2.2
colorama @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/colorama_1607707115595/work
conda==4.9.2
conda-build==3.21.4
conda-package-handling @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/41a2ba95-d84c-4c06-4d6e-5665866bc5b4/volume/conda-package-handling_1603018173200/work
conda-verify==3.4.2
contextlib2==0.6.0.post1
cryptography @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/41c3d62a-f1f8-46ce-414a-9adaf4ea7d96/volume/cryptography_1607636752064/work
cycler==0.10.0
Cython @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/0be2fe5e-2479-4ba4-6436-ec8985045960/volume/cython_1605457635746/work
cytoolz==0.11.0
dask @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/dask-core_1607706933335/work
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/diff-match-patch_1594828741838/work
distributed @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/f1421540-e56f-42ff-7213-7962831ed4ff/volume/distributed_1607714072407/work
Django==3.1.5
docutils==0.16
entrypoints==0.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.1.0
filelock==3.0.12
flake8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/flake8_1601911421857/work
Flask==1.1.2
flatbuffers==1.12
fsspec @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/fsspec_1602684995936/work
future==0.18.2
gast @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/gast_1597433534803/work
gevent @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/0c5c69a5-e371-4d0f-6829-02696fd7dd34/volume/gevent_1609093104720/work
glob2==0.7
gmpy2==2.0.8
google-auth==1.22.1
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
graphviz==0.16
greenlet @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/0051114e-81b1-4a15-4054-b5a71cd53179/volume/greenlet_1600874059672/work
grpcio==1.32.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
h5py==2.10.0
HeapDict==1.0.1
heroku==0.1.4
html5lib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/html5lib_1593446221756/work
idna @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/idna_1593446292537/work
imagecodecs @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/6d5bb329-9887-40d7-5c83-22b4e2ca104e/volume/imagecodecs_1603270471358/work
imageio @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/imageio_1594161405741/work
imagesize==1.2.0
importlib-metadata @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/importlib-metadata_1602276842396/work
iniconfig @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/iniconfig_1602780191262/work
intervaltree @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/intervaltree_1598376443606/work
ipykernel @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/73e8766c-12c3-4f76-62a6-3dea9a7da5b7/volume/ipykernel_1596206701501/work/dist/ipykernel-5.3.4-py3-none-any.whl
ipython @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/4f393720-ac1e-4c11-6939-afec7c0337aa/volume/ipython_1610725411441/work
ipython-genutils @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/ipython_genutils_1606773439826/work
ipywidgets @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/ipywidgets_1610481889018/work
isort @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/isort_1602603989581/work
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jedi==0.14.1
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/joblib_1607970656719/work
json5==0.9.5
jsonschema @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jsonschema_1602607155483/work
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyter_client_1601311786391/work
jupyter-console @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyter_console_1598884538475/work
jupyter-core @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/a00c6604-807b-490b-6c3f-c66a22f02fab/volume/jupyter_core_1606148990852/work
jupyterlab==2.2.6
jupyterlab-pygments @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_pygments_1601490720602/work
jupyterlab-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_server_1594164409481/work
jupyterlab-widgets @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_widgets_1609884341231/work
Keras==2.4.3
Keras-Applications @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/keras-applications_1594366238411/work
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
keyring @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/7fc9d8f2-8bd8-4148-5b20-ec7b4ae2249e/volume/keyring_1609353658137/work
kiwisolver @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/7f2d375c-30f6-458e-63e3-3be3b4be2918/volume/kiwisolver_1604014611853/work
lazy-object-proxy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/5927f8af-674c-485c-6607-a9c3a98dcf3a/volume/lazy-object-proxy_1607707356587/work
libarchive-c==2.9
llvmlite==0.34.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/2f2e9d7c-80fe-4a43-633f-52750fdb2409/volume/lxml_1606516857523/work
Markdown @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/ab9d027b-aa96-4f3e-4a67-57db8504e6b6/volume/markdown_1605111065503/work
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/61624fbb-2a49-420f-6e89-f3df5b5e7cab/volume/matplotlib-base_1603373809385/work
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.2.0
mkl-random==1.1.1
mkl-service==2.3.0
mock @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/mock_1607622725907/work
more-itertools @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/more-itertools_1605111547926/work
mpmath==1.1.0
msgpack @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/f823bc9b-1edb-4ee9-5d19-9de1ac61f3d9/volume/msgpack-python_1607965810722/work
multipledispatch==0.6.0
navigator-updater==0.2.1
nbclient @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nbclient_1602783176460/work
nbconvert @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d4b0787b-b6c8-4d28-5453-3381885d5b33/volume/nbconvert_1601914848300/work
nbformat @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nbformat_1610738111109/work
nbzip==0.1.0
nest-asyncio @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nest-asyncio_1606153767164/work
networkx @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/networkx_1598376031484/work
nltk @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nltk_1592496090529/work
nose @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nose_1606773131901/work
notebook @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/332710ad-ce98-460c-6576-c112295418f4/volume/notebook_1608835566118/work
numba @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/a92243fb-d564-44ee-7f97-342ce782c8cc/volume/numba_1600108029490/work
numexpr @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c18c3d5e-dc79-4b6b-6b23-59acb6850096/volume/numexpr_1609354654585/work
numpy==1.19.5
numpydoc @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/numpydoc_1605117425582/work
oauthlib==3.1.0
olefile==0.46
opencv-python==4.5.1.48
openpyxl @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/openpyxl_1610651698508/work
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/packaging_1607971725249/work
pandas==1.2.0
pandocfilters @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/315ac9bb-93fd-4adc-6795-345692fcfaed/volume/pandocfilters_1605120446899/work
parso==0.5.2
partd==1.1.0
path @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/91b74300-26ac-452d-76ae-e6d781176bc4/volume/path_1607537225637/work
pathlib2 @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/8e57d73a-998f-4fa8-5295-7c064efc1e48/volume/pathlib2_1607024984248/work
pathtools==0.1.2
patsy==0.5.1
pep8==1.7.1
pexpect @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pexpect_1605563209008/work
pickleshare @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pickleshare_1606932040724/work
Pillow @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/dfab893a-afa4-4cd2-5a7e-fb894890ea44/volume/pillow_1609786793862/work
pkginfo==1.6.1
pluggy==0.13.1
ply==3.11
prometheus-client @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/prometheus_client_1606344362066/work
prompt-toolkit @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/prompt-toolkit_1602688806899/work
protobuf==3.13.0
psutil @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/abb7a219-3a4a-4ff9-4158-148060faae29/volume/psutil_1598370243710/work
ptyprocess @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/ptyprocess_1609355006118/work/dist/ptyprocess-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
py @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/py_1607971587848/work
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycparser_1594388511720/work
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0.6
pydocstyle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pydocstyle_1598885001695/work
pydot==1.4.1
pydot-ng==2.0.0
pydotplus==2.0.2
pyerfa @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/4777125d-48ad-4a74-575f-3dfd04546bfd/volume/pyerfa_1606860211879/work
pyflakes==2.2.0
Pygments @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pygments_1610565767015/work
pylint @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9eebf2dc-3c74-4778-701c-c55b13929def/volume/pylint_1598624018844/work
pyodbc===4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyopenssl_1608057966937/work
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/656e0c1b-ef87-4251-4a51-1290b2351993/volume/pyrsistent_1600141745371/work
PySocks @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/ef943889-94fc-4539-798d-461c60b77804/volume/pysocks_1605305801690/work
pytest==0.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-jsonrpc-server_1600278539111/work
python-language-server==0.31.7
pytz @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pytz_1608922264688/work
PyWavelets @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/4c8a2af4-1e43-4df6-4c7a-c73342176802/volume/pywavelets_1601658329224/work
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==20.0.0
QDarkStyle==2.8.1
QtAwesome @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtawesome_1602272867890/work
qtconsole @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtconsole_1600870028330/work
QtPy==1.9.0
regex @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/75a20732-2306-4d51-79ce-516009aca709/volume/regex_1606773011423/work
requests @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1608241421344/work
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rope @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/rope_1602264064449/work
rsa==4.6
Rtree==0.9.4
ruamel-yaml==0.15.87
scikit-image==0.17.2
scikit-learn @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/2dacdc11-21e7-44f5-57b4-6b8eb6ceb626/volume/scikit-learn_1598376924598/work
scipy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9698578f-91da-4d5f-6fce-b26b1f42eb5a/volume/scipy_1597686637948/work
seaborn @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/seaborn_1608578541026/work
Send2Trash @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/send2trash_1607525499227/work
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/singledispatch_1602523705405/work
six @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/f983ba11-c9fe-4dff-7ce7-d89b95b09771/volume/six_1605205318156/work
sklearn==0.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
sortedcollections @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sortedcollections_1610133679826/work
sortedcontainers @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sortedcontainers_1606865132123/work
soupsieve @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/soupsieve_1607965878077/work
Sphinx @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinx_1610133430332/work
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinxcontrib-websupport_1597081412696/work
spyder==4.0.1
spyder-kernels==1.8.1
SQLAlchemy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/a37d3150-f8e8-4e5d-4ec2-01f3154ae8e6/volume/sqlalchemy_1608243746150/work
sqlparse==0.4.1
statsmodels @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c88b3fa8-c6a0-4ff4-6b2f-464912022a9d/volume/statsmodels_1606925355294/work
sympy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/347e855c-d365-447b-5b46-aa042092978f/volume/sympy_1608137682049/work
tables==3.6.1
tblib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tblib_1597928476713/work
tensorboard==2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.7.0
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.9.2
testpath==0.4.4
Theano==1.0.5
threadpoolctl @ file:///tmp/tmp9twdgx9k/threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
tifffile @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tifffile_1610739638720/work
toml @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/toml_1592853716807/work
toolz @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/toolz_1601054250827/work
tornado @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d531d395-893c-4ca1-6a5f-717b318eb08c/volume/tornado_1606942307627/work
tqdm @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tqdm_1609788246169/work
traitlets @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/traitlets_1602787416690/work
typed-ast @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/f24de662-b4e3-467b-58a8-199787662676/volume/typed-ast_1610484563580/work
typing-extensions @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/typing_extensions_1598376058250/work
ujson @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/689249ee-e8db-4ac6-59d6-84d404905c09/volume/ujson_1602523336695/work
unicodecsv==0.14.1
urllib3 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/urllib3_1606938623459/work
watchdog @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/5093631c-7a07-4a9a-7f4a-e1547c3d779d/volume/watchdog_1606939121159/work
wcwidth @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/wcwidth_1593447189090/work
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wrapt==1.12.1
wurlitzer @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59acb45c-07e7-4304-57af-e84f3889d3ef/volume/wurlitzer_1594753863419/work
xlrd @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/xlrd_1608072521494/work
XlsxWriter @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/xlsxwriter_1602692860603/work
xlwings==0.21.4
xlwt==1.3.0
xmltodict==0.12.0
yapf @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/yapf_1593528177422/work
zict==2.0.0
zipp @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/zipp_1604001098328/work
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9b4a6693-5968-464b-4257-b8041d527125/volume/zope.interface_1606940322645/work
```

Comment: Remove all the `@ {PATH}`, they are specific to your computer.

Comment: Would removing these lines with @ affect the working of the app in any way (functionality)?

Comment: Yes, because the `@ {PATH}`, is specific to your computer.

Comment: could you suggest a method whereby I can make this work without removing any lines of requirements that may be necessary in order for this app to run after pushing to heroku?

Comment: You don't need to remove the whole line, you just need to remove the `@ {PATH}` part, for example: `absl-py @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/absl-py_1607439979954/work` to `absl-py`